# In Django, is it possible to let Django to ignore sending email error report when

Tags: django, websocket

the url is starts with? /socket.io/1/websocket/327459101594
Just by searching through the document, seems there's no way to let Django ignore sending email error report based on request URL.

Does any one have any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own logging handler.

To check the url you could sublcass djangos [`AdminEmailHandler`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L73) and extend the `emit` method to check the url first.

```
class MyAdminEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):

  def emit(self, record):
     record.request
     # request information is available as request property
     super(MyAdminEmailHandler, self).emit(record)
```

Comment: I'll try that thanks! but how do i set Django to use that Handler?

Comment: oh. i get it. in the LOGGING config in settings i should change to use my overridden AdminEmailHandler.. Thanks!